# Spring Boot and Spring Data Jpa versions compatiblity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the latest (by the time of writing) Spring-Boot-starter-data-jpa (version 1.2.6.RELEASE). I find it actually uses the Spring-data-jpa version 1.7.3.RELEASE, which is considerably behind the latest (1.9).

Is it a supported approach to upgrade individual dependencies such as the Spring-data-jpa?  If I do this myself, for example, by declaring a direct dependency on the wanted newer version (may just override the version properties), any side effect you guys foresee?

The reason why I am doing this is that I need to use a special parameter in this annotation:`@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = JpaRepositoryWithI18n.class)`

That is not available in the supplied 1.7.3 jpa library.

Any workaround would be appreciated too.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I tested the following two ways: 1) declared a direct dependency to Spring-JPA-data 1.9.0 and excluded it from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2) upgrade Spring-boot-web-starter to 1.3.0m5

2) worked out well for me.   This is also what dunni's answer suggested.

I have not tested Andi's answer as this is a new project, we could easily upgrade the entire spring boot and regression test it without worrying too much about side-effects.

But I can see Andi's answer is an easier approach than 1). More importantly, it shows how you can upgrade other dependencies independently -- just overide the versions in parent pom.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported in that matter, that the Spring Boot test cases don't include newer versions. So your application might work with the newer version, but there may be some errors. With minor releases it's more likely to work without problems than with major version upgrades. You can also upgrade Spring Boot to 1.3.0.M5 (you should note however, that this is a milestone version, not yet the release).

Answer (score 5):

Spring Data JPA 1.9 is part of the Spring Data Gosling release train. As [described in the Gosling announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/spring-data-release-train-gosling-goes-ga) you can use it with Spring Boot 1.2:

> To upgrade to the new release train use the BOM we ship as described in our examples repository and configure its version to Gosling-RELEASE. If you’re using Spring Boot, upgrading to the release train is as easy as setting the Maven property spring-data-releasetrain.version to that version. Note, that to use Spring Data REST with Boot 1.2, you also need to upgrade to Spring HATEOAS 0.19.0.RELEASE (by setting the spring-hateoas.version property) and Jackson 2.5 or better (current 2.6.1 preferred, via the jackson.version property).

In short, add this to your pom:

```
<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: adding to Andy's answer: reference example- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/bom/pom.xml